# Round down float number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following float: 2.554 and I need to format as percentage using ruby/rails.

How to round down that float ?
I tried to use number_to_percentage but the value is displayed as 2.6 (round up)

Comment: `2.554.to_i #=> 2` or `2.554.floor #=> 2`.

Comment: What is the expected output? `2.5`? `2`?

Comment: To drop everything after 2 decimal places, use `2.555.truncate(2)`

Answer (score 3):

You cant use the round method specifying the number of digits to round.
 Sample

```
 2.554.round(2)
=> 2.55
```

With the next variant you can force to round down if the third digit after comma is less than 5

```
 2.555.round(2, half: :down)
=> 2.55
```